# Executing function within context of script and snapins

Tags: function, powershell, module, crm

I'm working on a script and like to keep things organized and clean, it's just how I am.  With that said, anytime I write a script it normally consists of two pieces - script.ps1 and config.xml.  Script is where the work is done and config.xml is where my variables are kept.  Occasionally I need to create a module that contains functions for some of the work the script's doing.

The issue I've run into now is that I'm having some trouble properly executing my custom functions if they contain pieces of another snappin or module.  Here's an example of what I'm doing...

Script.ps1 Snip:

```
 Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.Crm.Powershell
 $organization = "CRM-ORG"
 Get-CrmOrganization -Name $organization
 $Disable = CUST.Disable-CrmOrganization -OrganizationName $organization
 Write-Host $Disable
```

Module.psm1 Snip:

```
function CUST.Disable-CrmOrganization
{
    param([string]$OrganizationName)
    $isSuccess = $true

    Disable-CrmOrganization -Name $OrganizationName
    $orgData = Get-CrmOrganization -Name $OrganizationName

    if($orgData -ne "Disabled")
    {
        $isSuccess = $false
    }    

    $isSuccess
}
```

So what I'm trying to do here is create a function that outputs a true/false value based on how the operation went. Simple enough, right?  Wrong.  If I execute this code as it is, the Get operation within the function returns data on every organization within the CRM deployment.  If I move this function to the script and execute the code, it returns data on $OrganizationName only - the way it's intended.

Is there some kind of magic spell I have to chant prior to running this for it to work right?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn833066.aspx) it looks like `Get-CrmOrganization` isn't receiving any input.

> The Get-CrmOrganization cmdlet retrieves one or all of the
>   organizations in the deployment. **If no parameters are provided, the
>   cmdlet retrieves all organizations in the deployment.** If the Name
>   parameter is provided, the cmdlet retrieves the organization with the
>   specified name.

So it's doing exactly what you would expect if you didn't provide an input.

Not being totally au fait with PowerShell I'm guessing something is going wrong in the function parameter input. Perhaps you need some input parameters on the [function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347712.aspx) definition?

```
function <name> [([type]$parameter1[,[type]$parameter2])] { 
     <statement list> 
}
```

Comment: So the $OrganizationName variable I pass in contains the name of an organization, which is what the Get cmdlet should be searching on.  Whenever I run Get-CrmOrganization -Name $organization directly inside the script, it returns only data related to that organization.  Whenever I run  $Disable = CUST.Disable-CrmOrganization -OrganizationName $organization, the Get-CrmOrganization within that function returns data related to all instances.  It's like the Organization isn't being passed in or read correctly for some reason.

Comment: Have you debugged to ensure the name is actually correct within `CUST.Disable-CrmOrganization`?

Comment: Yup, the name goes into the function just fine.  Not only did I debug and see it, but the Disable-CrmOrganization -Name $OrganizationName operation runs and completes exactly as intended.

Comment: Just a guess, if you put `Get-CrmOrganization` before `Disable-CrmOrganization` does it make a difference? I wonder if it doesn't return details on disabled organisations so resorts to basic behaviour of displaying all organisations.

Comment: Tried that already thinking similarly, however the GET actually does return data on the disabled organization and after the transposition of the commands the same results came out.  At this point I'm wondering if this is an issue more centered around the CRM-Powershell SnapIn rather than Powershell context itself...